# Apache2 WSGI not importing python modules

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

Attempting to run a flask api on apache2.  All modules are installed; however, its telling me `ImportError: no module named itsdangerous`

run.py

```
import os
from restapi import app
if __name__=="__main__":
    port = (os.environ.get("PORT",5000))
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port, debug=True)
```

restapi.py

```
 from itsdangerous import (JSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer, BadSignature, SignatureExpired)
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
    from flask_cors import CORS
    from database import DataTable
    
    import simplejson as json
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = b'secret'
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    CORS(app)
    
    def get_credentials(request):           
        token = request.headers["Authorization"]       
        if not token: return json.dump({"success": False, "message": "Authorization Missing"})                
        s = Serializer(app.config["SECRET_KEY"])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)                    
            return {"success": True,"id":data}
        except:
            return {"success": False, "message": "Valid Token Missing"}
    
    @app.route("/auth", methods=["POST"])
    def auth():
        import auth    
        return json.dumps(auth.process(request))
...
```

WSGI file:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.6

import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/applications/python3.9-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages')
from restapi import app as application
application.secret_key = b'secret'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: WSGI installs its own instance of Python. It is possible that the modules you want to import are not installed in that particular instance.

Comment: Interesting.  So how do I manage to import what I need?

Comment: First find out if you have more than one Python instance. I can't see your system so that is only a suspicion. Then find the `pip` installed with that instance (location is platform-dependent: on Windows it is in folder Scripts) and use *that* `pip` to install the 3rd-party modules you want.

Comment: I have 2.7, 3.8 and 3.9.  How do I know which one wsgi is using?

Comment: The answer to that is platform-dependent. Can't help, sorry.

Comment: How you installed modules try installing them with sudo command if you haven't